# Configuring controller in java to bypass system proxy

Tags: java, http-proxy

I have

```
public void test(String domain, String version, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException {
    String strUrl = domain + "?get-wms-list.go?" + "service=web&version=" + version
        + "&request=GetCapabilities";
    log.info("download " + strUrl);
    pass(strUrl, response);
}
```

However, the system proxy settings keeps preventing me from accessing the above.

Comment: What error do you get? And FYI: a proxy is an external gateway. If your network administrator routes your network packets through a proxy there's no (simple) way to avoid the proxy.

Comment: Did you stablish the propper authentication params for the proxy connection?